# Oracle APEX 20.2 Select list drop down values appear on another monitor, not near select list in Edge or Chrome ok?

Tags: oracle-apex

In a newly created Oracle APEX 20.2 form the values in the select lists do not appear under the select list, instead they appear on another monitor.  This occurs when using Microsoft Edge and in Chrome, including in the application builder drop downs
Suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your installation of APEX 20.2 was completed successfully? Did you update the image files on the web server? Can you reproduce the issue on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: I am using Oracle ATP and did update the image files on the ORDS server.  Good thought on the apex.oracle.com test, and it occurred there as well. I am now thinking it has to do with my docking station and multiple windows so am looking at that.  Thanks for the suggestions.